# Applying an expression depending on a condition in a loop

Tags: c, r

I guess this question surely has been asked several times, but I couldn't find anything.

I have a function that depends on an argument (`caseset`) which can be of two different kinds. Depending on its nature, in a loop I need to perform an operation rather than another. Since the nature of the object is known at the beginning, it appears to me inefficient and inelegant to have an `if` statement each time in the loop. Ideally, I'd apply the right expression each time and choose it atop of the loop. Here is a code to have an idea of what I'm after.

```
SEXP doSomething(SEXP anObject, SEXP caseset, SEXP isMat) {
  /*
  * here anObject is an external pointer to a C structure,
  * caseset is either a character matrix or a data.frame made of character columns.
  */
 int i,j,nrow,ncol;
 int isMatrix = LOGICAL(isMat)[0];
 const char *field;
 /*
  * Determine the number of rows and columns in each case
 */
 if (isMatrix) {
   ncol = length(VECTOR_ELT(getAttrib(caseset,R_DimNamesSymbol),1));
   nrow = length(caseset)/ncol;
 } else {
   ncol = length(caseset);
   nrow = length(VECTOR_ELT(caseset,0));
 }
 for (i=0;i<nrow;i++) {
   for (j=0;j<ncol;j++) {
     if (isMatrix) {
       field = CHAR(STRING_ELT(caseset,j*nrow+i));
     } else {
       field = CHAR(STRING_ELT(VECTOR_ELT(caseset,j),i));
     }
     /*
      * Do stuff involving field and anObject
     */    
   }
 }
 return result;
}
```

I'm writing a C function callable from R. I'm passing R objects (the `SEXP` types). The `caseset` object can be either a matrix or a `data.frame`. I'm processing a row at the time and since the two objects stores their element very differently, to get the `(i,j)` value of the table you have to move differently. Note the `if` condition stated each time (which for every call of `doSomething` will have the same result). The rest of the function is pretty long.

I can certainly:

- move the `if` condition outside the loop and rewrite two identical blocks of code (except for one line) depending on the value of `isMatrix`;
- write two almost identical functions and "dispatch" the right one depending on the nature of `caseset`.

However, both the above options look inelegant to me. I'd prefer to have something that let you apply the right line  in the loop without checking the condition each time and without having to rewrite twice code.

Comment: Personally I don't think there is anything wrong with either of the approaches noted in your bullet points. However, if you're really concerned with the aesthetics of your code, why not just use C++ / Rcpp which (IMO) will allow you to write much more elegantly?

Comment: @nrussell Tx for your comment. I'm wrapping a C library and migrating with C++/Rcpp would be too much work at this time, considering also that I know C much better than C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C is not exactly well known for elegance.  Other languages might allow you to use some sort of iterator perhaps.  Checking isMatrix twice is not bad.  But of course you might need to check more times or maybe support more types.

Consider using two internal functions based on isMat:

```
SEXP doSomething(SEXP anObject, SEXP caseset, SEXP isMat) {
/*
 * here anObject is an external pointer to a C structure,
 * caseset is either a character matrix or a data.frame made of character     columns.
 */
  return LOGICAL(isMat)[0] ? doSomethingMatrix(anObject,caseset) : doSomethingFrame(anObject,caseset);
}
static doSomethingMatrix(SEXP anObject, SEXP caseset) {
  int i,j,nrow,ncol;
  const char *field;

  ncol = length(VECTOR_ELT(getAttrib(caseset,R_DimNamesSymbol),1));
  nrow = length(caseset)/ncol;

  for (i=0;i<nrow;i++) {
    for (j=0;j<ncol;j++) {
      field = CHAR(STRING_ELT(caseset,j*nrow+i));

      // Share the long processing code between the two functions
      doStuffField(anObject,field);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Tx for your answer. Yes, I guess that sharing the processing part is maybe the most elegant (maybe with a macro rather than a function).

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array of function pointers.
For example, to program a calculator, instead of:

```
if (c == '+')
   return (a + b);
elif (c == '-')
   return (a - b);
...
```

You could do something like:

```
char *op = {'+', '-', '/', '*', '%', 'whatever you want', NULL};
for (int i=0, op[i] && op[i] != c, i++};
if (op[i])
   return (my_function_ptr[i](a, b));
```

And it would call the function number 'i' in the array.